# ReactJS + flux - how to handle session-like parameters (pseudoauthorization)

Tags: reactjs, flux, react-router

Here's the usecase:

I have 2 components in my reactjs application. Both components are fed with data from remote server - via websockets. I don't want my components nor stores to be aware of data source - all websocket logic resides in ActionCrators and something I call SocketListeners.

Here's the example of such a listener:

```
var listen = function (socket) {
  socket
    .on(Messages.LIGHTS_CHANGED, function (newConfiguration) {

      AppDispatcher.dispatch({
        type: LightActionTypes.SUBSTITUTE_LIGHT_CONFIGURATION,
        payload: newConfiguration
      });

    })      
};

module.exports = {
  listen: listen
};
```

Since it is a websocket, I need to know the remote url. 
I'd like to ask my user to provide this url on my home page - and before that, my components (actually - routes) should not be available and user should be redirected to the page where he is able to specify this URL.

So I need something which looks like a **login flow** - but instead of login and password, remote url is crucial property here.

How would you manage this session-like state?

**I tried something like this:**

In my form-like home view I have a function:

```
handleConnectionConfirmed: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ActionCreator.saveRemoteUrl(
      this.state.remoteUrl
    );
  },
```

which causes to update my ConfigurationStore:

```
var _lightsUrl = '';
var _temperatureUrl = '';

var ConfigurationStore = {
  lightsSocketEndpoint: function () {
    return _lightsUrl;
  },

  temperatureSocketEndpoint: function () {
    return _temperatureUrl;
  }

};
```

And then both my components have:

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    ActionCreator.init();
  },
```

Init function:

```
init: function () {
    _socket = WebSocketFactory.lightsWebSocket();
    SocketListener.listen(_socket);
  },
```

One last snippet:

```
lightsWebSocket: function () {
    return io.connect(
      ConfigurationStore.lightsSocketEndpoint()
    )
  },
```

**The problem is:** as soon as I refresh any page, of course my ConfigurationStore is cleared.

How can I make it *somehow* persistent without using an external storage?

Also, do you know how can I configure react-router so that it could redirect me to 'login' page when no remote url is specified and user tries to open site where one of those components resides?

Answer (score 3):

Use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). For example:

In your store's constructor do:

```
_lightsUrl = localStorage.getItem('lightsUrl') || '';
```

And in the dispatch handler of the store:

```
_lightsUrl = newLightsUrl;
localStorage.setItem('newLightsUrl');
```

Here's a nice tutorial which does authentication this way (don't mind the 'Rails' part): http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/01/29/react-plus-flux-backed-by-rails-api-part-2/

Comment: I think using localStorage/sessionStore is cleaner though. You don't need an extra library, plus you don't need to send this url to the server with every request (which happens with cookies). Unless you have to support IE8, in that case: use cookies and... good luck.